# Button Not Displaying Image When Clicked

Tags: button, graphics, jpanel, paint, repaint

I am fairly new to Java and am working on an applet that uses graphics in a JPanel.

In one class, I have implemented the actionListener to perform an action when a button is clicked.

```
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
{
    JButton source = (JButton) e.getSource();

    if (source == popDensityButton)
    {
        GraphicsDisplay.population ();
    }
```

In the GraphicsDisplay class which extends the JPanel, the code is as follows:

```
public void paint (Graphics g)
{

    g.drawImage (world_map, 5, 40, this);
    update (g);

}

public void update (Graphics g)
{
    if (population == true)
    {
        g.drawString ("STRING", 100, 100); // used to see if the button works

    }
}

public static void population ()
{
    population = true;
}
```

When the popDensityButton is clicked, nothing happens.
"STRING" is only displayed when the window is resized.

What is the best way to fix this?
I have a feeling it has to do with the invoking a repaint() method since the panel is automatically repainted when the window is resized.

Answer (score 0):

Methods like `update(Graphics g)` and `paint(Graphics g)` are only called when necessary to save calculation time. So yes, after `GraphicsDisplay.population()` you have to call `repaint()` to see the new result.

Comment: I tried adding repaint() after GraphicsDisplay.population(). Nothing changed: "STRING" only displayed when the window was resized. Is there anything else that needs to be added? Does repaint() need to be used in the GraphicsDisplay class?

Comment: As far as I can see, the string should be displayed in `source`. If so, then you have to write `source.repaint()`.